# Conditional Put on dynamodb using boto3 with global secondary Index

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a dynamodb with
hashkey :ContactID
Global Secondary Index :EmailIndex (Email),
MobileIndex(Mobile)

I want to insert items to dynamodb with a condition that the new item doesn't have
EmailId or Mobile number already exists in table

I heard about **conditional put** is it possible to use that for the above condition.

It should be noted that Email and Mobile fields are not always present in the item

Below is the code which I now use to insert item

```
table = dynamodb.Table('Contacts')
response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'ContactID': str(uuid.uuid4()),
        'Email': 'user@ymail.com',
        'Mobile':'020298377783',
        'City':"Alaska",

    },
    Expected={'Email': {'Exists': False}, 'Mobile':{'Exists': False}}

)
```

But it keeps on adding item even if I give same Email or Mobile

Answer (score 0):

If each item is sure to have an email and a mobile associated with it, you could create a table with a composite partition key schema, where the partition key is `mobile_email=[{Mobile},{Email}]`. Then, you can use an `attribute_not_exists(mobile_email)` condition on your PutItem request to prevent new items from being created.